# Hide top search box in OpenPublic based on OpenOmega 7.x-1.0 (default theme)

Tags: views, 7, blocks, theming

I am new to Drupal and am trying to hide the top search box that comes with a default install of OpenPublic since it blocks my title.
[image]

My issue is, when I click

1. Configure Layout
2. Site Wide Before
3. Edit and then the X....it only removes it temporarily.

[image]

After I click "Done" and then "Save Changes", the box reappears.

I can add the Search block to other parts of the site, like the footer, but I don't see the top box referenced anywhere in site Blocks.  It seems to be buried somewhere in "Main page content".  When I try to edit that box, I can't find a setting that relates to search in "Main page content"

EDIT:
Here is what my "themes" section looks like:
[image]

Comment: It's usually added in the theme; what theme are you using?

Comment: OpenOmega 7.x-1.0 (default theme)